# Why is the OCI image created at an incorrect time with buildpacks

Tags: image, docker, buildpack

Hi StackOverflow community,
i'm learing buildpacks form https://buildpacks.io/docs/, and i successed built a image with `pack build myapp --builder cnbs/sample-builder:bionic`, but the CREATED time shows incorrectly.

```
REPOSITORY                 TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
paketobuildpacks/run       base-cnb   5eaa2a599cd5   12 days ago    87.9MB
cnbs/sample-stack-run      bionic     0b2076fcd92b   13 days ago    70.2MB
cnbs/sample-builder        bionic     39da2bad90ed   41 years ago   180MB
buildpacksio/lifecycle     0.11.3     c4e1a4508bb6   41 years ago   15.7MB
myapp                      latest     288fcaabda89   41 years ago   300MB
paketobuildpacks/builder   base       0e5a0d1ee6bc   41 years ago   684MB
```

Why it said 41 years ago?

Answer (score 1):

For reproducible builds, buildpaks don't include timestamps in the manifest. The 40+ years ago is the zero value when that timestamp is not set. They've documented this behavior at:
https://buildpacks.io/docs/reference/reproducibility/#consequences-and-caveats

Comment: How can i do if want to show CREATED in correct ?